# Getting 'you cannot reject the app version in the current state' error trying to reject binary waiting for review

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm trying to reject an app binary from app store connect because I discovered a bug and made a new build.
The application status is 'waiting for review'.

There's a button to reject the binary shown here.

[image]

Clicking 'remove this version from review' presents me with the dialog below. When I click 'Remove' the red error message appears and the page is redirected to app store connect home page

[image: When I click 'Remove' the red error message appears and the page is redirected to app store connect home page]

I tried a lot but I get the same error and redirection every time.

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Thanks. I can remove now. But in my case, it is not a few hours. It's three days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried again after a few hours and it worked and I didn't get the error.

Answer (score 11):

You need to go to the TestFlight, expire the build and then go back and try to remove from review. It works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try to reject the binary in App Store Connect **iOS app**

Couldn't reject it on App Store Connect site, but I rejected it in the app without problems - only 4 minutes after app status changed to "Waiting for Review"