# Remove the app from the "Waiting for review"

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I uploaded a new version of my app a few hours ago and it is now in "Waiting for review" state. there is a link there "remove this version from review", when I click this link and confirm the message to delete, I see this message. [image]

I want to update another binary, But unable to remove this.
Is there any way I can remove and add a new binary?

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58018627/getting-you-cannot-reject-the-app-version-in-the-current-state-error-trying-to - posted a couple of hours ago.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I tried a few way but can't solve it.